# Moving away from using a table to display a list of user profiles

Tags: gui-design, tables, lists

I'm looking for a new inventive way to display a list of users that can be selected and managed. I was thinking about a grid type view with animated drop for more details. Any help with this would be great. See image for table view mock.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's becoming a stock response for this kind of thing these days, but take a look at card-based layouts.

In this case, you would represent each user profile as a *card*.  By doing this, you are left with discrete blocks of content per profile, with a standard layout used by all cards.

By using this approach, you still maintain a common basic layout per profile shown, but you've got more scope for interesting layout within each card.  Comparing data between two profiles is *slightly* harder, but in general a user is still able to cast their eye over the screen and see differences between individuals due to the common layout.

Because you're not limiting yourself to a single table row per profile, you're also not forcing each contained field of data to be the same height - you can do things like making a profile image larger, or a displayed name have a bigger type size... most of which can introduce problems with cell or row height in a traditional table layout.

It's not an approach which is appropriate across the board, but it's certainly another approach worth attempting if you want more options for a compelling layout.

Answer (score 3):

What i'm seeing there is tabular data. If it's tabular data, why not show it in a table?

It takes the least screen space, it's easy to read, paginate, order and most important: compare data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, thing is... I very much doubt there will be huge numbers in this list. It's a list of users that can manage a dashboard. So I was thinking why not have them as 'cards' on a grid? That the administrator can hover and edit etc.